# Can I insert multiple values to a MS Access record using an SQL statement from VB 6.0?

Tags: mysql, vb6

I just want to know whether I could insert multiple values to a record by using an SQL statement from Visual Basic 6.0.

I have a database containing fields `rollno, name, subopt1, subopt2`. So instead of these 2 fields `subopt1,subopt2` I want to insert it as a multiple values in a single field `Subjects`.

Is it possible to do it using an SQL statement from the Visual Basic 6 while inserting records. If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Is it for MS Access or for MySQL? The title says access but the tag is mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need to create the new `Subjects` field in your table. You can do this with ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
  ADD Subjects VARCHAR(50);
```

Then, you can concatenate your two values into a single string using `&` in VB6:

```
Dim sSubjects As String
sSubjects = subopt1 & "," & subopt2
```

Finally, use the `sSubjects` variable in your SQL Statement.

When you read the data back from the database and want to separate `subopt1` and `subopt2`, you can use the [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function):

```
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim sSubjects As String
Dim sSubOpt(1 To 9) As String

sSubjects = "opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,opt5,opt6,opt7,opt8,opt9"

Dim options As Variant
options = Split(sSubjects, ",")

For iCounter = 1 To 9
    sSubOpt(iCounter) = options(iCounter - 1)
Next
```

Comment: Hi Étienne Laneville, thanks for your code. But by using the select statement, i want to select only one value(subject) from that field. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: In my example I used a comma to separate `subopt1` and `subopt2`. If you want to split the `Subjects` field back into two values, you can use the `Split` function. I have edited my answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 2):

If you need only 2 fields as mentioned in the question then Étienne's answer would be enough. But if you need more flexibility and you may have unknow count of values then you can create another table e.g. RollSubject (rollsubjectId, rollno, subject) and insert your values there. You can comment if you need further information.

Comment: Hi Caesar, thanks for your reply. As you have mentioned the total subjects count is 9. So can you help me in concatenating all the subjects.

Comment: Plus one, sounds like adding another table is the best solution. I.e. changing the database design